# org-mode defvar-alias error when trying to use org-clock-in

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have installed org-mode Org-mode version 7.9.2+ (7.9.2+-GNU-Emacs-24-3 @ /Users/jmankoff/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20131118/) using ELPA and emaics version GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (i386-apple-darwin11.4.2, NS apple-appkit-1138.51) of 2012-11-21 on jcmankoff.hcii.cs.cmu.edu.home

When I load org-mode and try to clock-in (using org-clock-in) I get the error byte-code: Symbol's function definition is void: org-defvaralias

I have googled around and found various suggestions (ensure that org-mode is installed in an emacs with no org-related stuff loaded; try load-library org-compat; and so on). The only thing that made a difference is that if I load-library org-compat the error changes to say that org-refresh-properties is void.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this error. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the elpa version (which should be 8.x) is conflicting with the version that comes with emacs? If you do C-h f org-mode and then go to the source code to which file does it jump to?